# Is there a way to populate a angular-ui-bootstrap dropdown-toggle every time I open it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to do a dropdown-toggle like the one that Facebook has for notifications.

I need to populate a list of notifications on a dropdown-toggle every time I open it, with $http or $resource.

I can't find any event or any variable to watch. The documentation is here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdownToggle

The only thing I've found is that the css class "open" is added/removed from the dropdown when it's opened/closed. I could watch that, but it feels like an ugly hack.

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with the current version of angular-ui's `dropdown.js` ([commit 73c2dea548](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/73c2dea54872714184168f64623aa0dd5f0aeb58/src/dropdown/dropdown.js)) that in the the GitHub repository, they have exposed an `is-toggled` attribute that you can use to find out when the dropdown was opened.  It seems like it's not in the 0.10 release of angular-ui bootstrap so you have to make your own custom build.

Although it does have an is-toggled function, there is a small bug where it does not get fired the first time you open it.  I have created a fix for it which is in the plunkr that I will link to later on.  The change I made was on line 96 to change it from `angular.isDefined(wasOpen)` to `angular.isDefined(isOpen)`.

Once you have this file you can add an `is-toggled` attribute to element with the `dropdown` class.

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown" on-toggle="toggled(open)">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle">
    Click me for a dropdown, yo!
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
      <a>{{choice}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

In your controller:

```
  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
    var now = new Date();
    $log.info('i was opened...',open,now);
    if (open) {
      $scope.items.push("last opened at " + now);
    }
  };
```

And here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rdVC8vfvbdtsnkk7bWZn?p=preview

Comment: BTW, if you just add `is-open="open"` to the html then you shouldn't need my changes, you can just use that version of dropdown.js.  I discovered that while making [this bug fix](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2121)

Comment: Using the repository version, adding `is-open="open"` to the html and using `$scope.$watch("open", function(newValue) { if(newValue) { ... } });` in the controller worked fine. Thanks!